# How to create an image grid with React Native after collecting data from Axios?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create an image grid like the following on React Native.

[image]

I have managed to extract the data from https://pokeapi.co/ using Axios. My code is as the following so far but doesnt seem to work. The code below retrieves data from the API and I have set that data to setPokemon (How to I access this data) I have tried to assign that data to {data} below to be used inside the flatlist but its not working. It doesnt seem to assign the data at all.

```
export default function App() {

const [pokemons, setPokemon] = useState([])
//Fetching Pokemon from online database
async function fetchPokemon() {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50')
  setPokemon(data.results) // ASSIGN DATA TO setPokemon
  } 
}
//Hook to fetch Pokemon upon component mount
useEffect(() => {
fetchPokemon()
}, [])

const renderPokemon = (item, index) => {
return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
}

const {data} = setPokemon // ALL POKEMON SHOULD BE INSIDE THIS 

return (
 <SafeAreaView>
  <FlatList
    style={styles.container}
    data={data} // ALL POKEMON SHOULD BE INSIDE THIS 
    renderItem={renderPokemon}
    keyExtractor={pokemons => `key-${pokemons.name}`}
  >
  </FlatList>
 </SafeAreaView>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1
},
});
```

Any tips on this?

Comment: `{data} = setPokemon` this is the setter. Do you mean `{data} = pokemons`?

Comment: I've tried to assign pokemons to {data} as well but it doesnt seem to be working. (I console.log {data} to test this and it says 'undefined'

Comment: Why do you expect it to have the property `data`? Have you tried yet to `console.log(pokemons)`

Comment: Im trying to assign all the pokemons to {data} as it is a prop for the flatlist. I have also tried logging pokemons but its 'undefined' still

Comment: if `pokemons` is undefined after `setPokemon(data.results)` then `data.results` is undefined. Simply console.log `data` in your fetchPokemon function to see what is actually being returned from the api.

Comment: In general if you don't know what the structure of some data is, log it and have a look.

Comment: I have console.log data.results and it displays all the data in the console, which is why im confused why it is 'undefined' when I try to assign it to a variable {data}. Im assigning this data.results via setPokemon outside the sync function - Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: `const {someField} = objectWithSomeField` is the syntax for object destructuring. Can you please post what data.results is?

Comment: The data displayed when console.logging (data.results) is https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50 starting from 'results'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access data from the state setter function. After calling `setPokemon(5)`, `pokemons` will be 5.

`const {data} = pokemons` expects your data to be an object, but you've initialized it as a list, and it looks like you're trying to populate it as a list. Do you mean to write `const data = pokemons` to simply rename it rather than destructuring it?

Assuming that `data.results` is a list of stuff, here's what the working component will look like:

```
 function App() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  async function fetchPokemon() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=50')
    setPokemon(data.results)
    } 
  }
  
  useEffect(fetchPokemon, [])
  
  const renderPokemon = (item, index) => {
    return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  };
    
  return (
   <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      style={styles.container}
      data={pokemons} // ALL POKEMON SHOULD BE INSIDE THIS 
      renderItem={renderPokemon}
      keyExtractor={pokemons => `key-${pokemons.name}`}
    >
    </FlatList>
   </SafeAreaView>
   );
  };
```

Edit: it seems like there is another error related to object destructuring. If you look at the FlatList docs the renderItem requires a function with this signature: `(o: {item: T, index: number}) => Element`. Simply update your renderPokemon function.

Comment: I've tried putting pokemons into the data prop for flatlist but doesnt seem to be working either. Also tried const data = pokemons but doesnt work

Comment: Ok, answer is complete and tested.